# Saving Image to disk loaded from cloud storage?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, firebase-storage

I am loading an image to `img` `src` from cloud storage using `getSignedURL` method and image is loaded. Now i want to give user ability to download that image.

for that i searched and most common way was to add `<a href='imagelink'/>` but it did not downloaded the image instead followed the url and showed in the browser.

Even tried the `download` tag like `<a download href='imglink'/>` but no success.

Can't use `fetch` as `CORS` is not available.

Another point: is it possible to do the same without making two calls to image link ?

Converting to `base64` and then saving may increase the size of file.